# Angular Reactive Forms ngSubmit not working for single input control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular15

I have a issue while using Angular reactive forms.

Please check this forked [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdpzpq-6qjar3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fname-editor%2Fname-editor.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fname-editor%2Fname-editor.component.html) example from official Angular reactive forms docs, name editor form.
In this example form has only one `input` control.
I am using `ngSubmit` on `<form>` element and `<button>` is `type="submit"`.

But when I submit form the page reloads. The default submit behaviour is not prevented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(ngSubmit)` must be used with `[ngForm]` else the submit button will trigger the standard HMTL submit.

This means you'll have to create a `FormGroup` for your `FormControl`.

Comment: that makes sense. I guess that I could use type button and add click to submit form, and remove ngSubmit. What do you think about that approach?